# Git: How to make sure that a group of files are identical to what they were at some time in the past

Tags: git

Lets say that someone makes a bad push and changes a file that he didn't mean to ( amazingly this happens sometimes ). 
Then say he realized it and reverted his mistake.

How can I verify that the file is unchanged afterwards, that is, how can i verify that he successfully undid his mistake?

How do you do the same for a group of files?

And finally, how do you do this if you are comparing files at a different time in history, where neither is the current version?

Comment: you can also just check them out at a known-good commit (whatever commit corresponds to a time/date you know the files are in a good state) and if there _is_ a diff 1) look at it 2) commit it.

Comment: Since this is tagged [git], `git rev-parse commit1:path/to/file` `commit2:path/to/maybe/another/file`. If the output lines aren't the same, the files are different.

Comment: @AD7six: That sounds logical. I'm wondering how the syntax would look like to do this.

Comment: How to checkout a file at a specific commit will be an existing question+answer. Ala: `git log` (pick a commit) `git checkout commit list of file paths`.

Comment: @AD7six: Where commit would be the commit id I assume. Sounds practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html:

```
git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>…]
This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.
...
<path>…
The <paths> parameters, when given, are used to limit the diff to the named
paths (you can give directory names and get diff for all files under them).
```

So:

```
git diff deadbeef cafebabe -- pom.xml src/main/resources src/test/resources
```

will let me see the differences between those two (abbreviated) commit hashes for my pom.xml and all the files under src/main/resources and src/test/resources.

[[ Keep in mind that this compares the full files/dirs as they exist at those revisions. It does *not* merely compare the specific changes introduced by those two specific commits. ]]

--

OP asks:

```
Can't you skip the -- ? That's what I did and didn't notice problems.
```

Absolutely.  The `--` option is to remove possible ambiguities in the command.  In cases where the command is smart enough to resolve the ambiguity itself (as is usually the case with git commands), the '--' can be omitted (as indicated by the brackets around the `--` in the man page).

What possible ambiguities? They are probably rare if you keep to sane filenames and branch/tag names, but they are possible.  For example, note that the man page says there are both valid git diff commands:

```
(1) git diff [--options] [<commit>] [--] [<path>…]
This form is to view the changes you have in your working tree
relative to the named <commit>. ...

(2) git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>…]
This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.
```

Let's say I have a file called 'foo' in the current directory.  I also happen to have a tag called 'foo' (that's the commit where I added the file called 'foo').

```
git diff deadbeef foo
```

What does this command do? (1) Does it compare file `foo` from revision `deadbeef` to file `foo` as it is now in my work dir? (2) Or does it compare the whole source tree from revision `deadbeef` to the whole source tree in tag `foo`?

I believe it will do (2).  So in case I really want interpretation (1), I can use:

```
git diff deadbeef -- foo
```

--

One thing nice about git is the commands are fairly consistent in structure.  Many commands use:

```
git <command> [--options] <commit reference(s), if needed?> [--] [<path> ...]

git diff HEAD^ -- README 
git log HEAD^ -- README 
git checkout HEAD^ -- README 
git reset HEAD -- foo
```

Perhaps you won't run into ambiguities for `git diff` very often and if you did run into it, its any easy fix to run the command again using the '--'. But sometimes its nice to use the double-dash to ensure no ambiguity (or to resolve an ambiguity if there really is one), especially if the command is potentially destructive (e.g. `checkout`, `reset`).

Comment: Can't you skip the -- ? That's what I did and didn't notice problems.

Answer (score 1):

Diff the file with itself:

```
git diff HEAD^^ HEAD file
```

If you leave off the `file` it'll diff the commits.

Comment: Ahh. HEAD^^ standing for 2 commits prior to HEAD I assume.

Comment: Can you replace HEAD and HEAD^^ with for example id of 2 different commits? That's seems to work when I try it.

Comment: @Skúli yes, HEAD is just pointing to a commit, using the commit hash will do just fine

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is exactly the title question, this will perform somewhat-to-noticeably better -- diff's extremely good, but comparing a pair of 20-byte codes you already have is always going to be better than extracting the of all differing files.  `rev-parse` turns any reference into the sha of the object it refers to, so:

```
if test "$(git rev-parse commit1:path/to/file)" \
      = "$(git rev-parse commit2:path/to/maybe/another/file)"; then
        # the files are the same
else
        # they're different
fi
```

or if you're eyeballing it,

```
git rev-parse commit1:path/to/blob-or-tree commit2:path/to/another
```

will do the trick, though if directory trees differ you'll sooner or later use `git diff --name-only` on the two tree refs to find which ones.

Comment: Explain the downvote, please? This works and it's vastly more efficient when checking entire subdirectories.

Comment: This answer could be significantly improved if you give more explanation as to how it works. It's not obvious that `git rev-parse` can be used to "diff" files (not even after reading [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html)). Also, `git diff` is already pretty darn efficient, you're going to have to make a strong case for why `git rev-parse` can sometimes be better.

Comment: @Cupcake (rev-parse doesn't compare content, but OP says several times he wants only to ensure the differences are gone.)

Comment: @jthill: I've been comparing 'git rev-parse commit1:pathTofileOrDirectory commit2:pathTofileOrDirectory' and  'git diff commit1 commit2 -- pathTofileOrDirectory'. Both of them seem to tell me if the bad commit was successfully undone. rev-pars gives me 2 hashes that if similar then success. diff outputs nothing if the undo was successful. To me the diff approach seems better mainly because I don't have to repeat the pathOrFileName. Also if the there is a difference it can be nice to see it on the spot. Your 'if else' approach has the minus of being much longer. Does this make sense?

Comment: of course.  The diffs are much more convenient, and this isn't  performance-sensitive, it's pretty clear-cut here.